# Retain picklist selection on form edit

Tags: asp-classic, picklist

Hi I am creating a form that will write entries to a database.  This form can be opened and edited.  I want the form to open with the previous answers.Some of the  fields in the forms are picklists.  I have created an array to display the picklist options.  When the form is submitted the selected option is inserted into the database.  However, when I open the form again, that selection does not appear in the picklist box, rather the first item in the array appears.

Here is the code I am using:

```
dim options, ar1, selectedvalue1, val1

selectedvalue1=Request.Form("pref")

ar1=array("Phone","Email","Trial","Employee","Beta")

for each val1 in ar1
options=options & "<option value=""" & val1 & """"
if val1=selectedvalue1 then options=options & " selected"
options=options & ">" & val1
next

<BR><BR>Preference: <form method="post"><select name="pref">
 <%=options%>
</select><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your For Each loop you are using a variable named "val1", but then you reference just the "val" variable inside the loop. Because of this, the value is not being set on the options.

Change your loop to:

```
for each val1 in ar1
options=options & "<option value=""" & val1 & """"
if val1=selectedvalue1 then options=options & " selected"
options=options & ">" & val1
next
```

Comment: I did correct that, thank you, BUT although the data I selected ("Beta") is in the database, when I open the form to edit again, "Phone" appears in the picklist as my choice.  I want it to display "Beta".

Comment: @user2051481 Are you querying the data base to grab the value "Beta" and setting it as your "selectedvalue1" value? If you are, please update your original post with that code too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Luke.
I had to make some changes. I am querying the database for "dboptions". This code is working:

```
dim options, ar1, val1

ar1=array("Phone","Email","Trial","Employee","Beta")

for each val1 in ar1
options=options & "<option value=""" & val1 & """"
if val1=dboptions then 
options=options & " selected"
End If
options=options & ">" & val1
next

<BR><BR>Preference: <select name="pref">
 <%=options%>
</select><br>
```